# Подключение к удаленному серверу из SQL-скрипта (PostgreSQL 12)

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли обратиться к таблице в базе данных Postgres, находящейся на другом сервере, напрямую из SQL-скрипта?
Нужно автоматизировать обновление данных на prod-сервере с помощью хранимой процедуры, которая копирует записи из локальной БД в удаленную.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html?

Comment: @Ainar-G, точно, спасибо огромное!